# How to return output as NULL object in ifelse condition when the condition is FALSE

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, geom-point

I am worried if someone can help me for getting output from `ifelse()` function in R. I am using mtcars dataset. I wants if condition is TRUE then the command should return a data frame and if condition is FALSE then the command should return a NULL object. I shall further use this command in `geom_point()` function for argument `data`. When the condition in ifelse is FALSE the output will be a NULL object for `data` argument in geom_point() function with no points. The command I have used is given below but it resulted in error:

```
data("mtcars")
ifelse(dim(filter(mtcars, mpg < 10))[1] > 0, 
       as.data.frame(filter(mtcars, mpg > 10)), 
       as.null(filter(mtcars, mpg < 10)))
```

Here is the error: `Error in ans[npos] <- rep(no, length.out = len)[npos] :  replacement has length zero In addition: Warning message: In rep(no, length.out = len) : 'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL`

However, if I run individual commands like `as.data.frame(filter(mtcars, mpg > 10))` and `as.null(filter(mtcars, mpg < 10))` the output is okay. But using it within the ifelse function, it shows an error for the second command (**NULL object**).

My concern is that if condition is `FALSE` the ifelse function should return the output as **NULL**, so this could be used in `geom_point()` function for the data argument to hide points from the plot.

I would be really grateful for your assistance in this matter.

Thanks

Comment: Try with `if`-`else` instead of `ifelse`: `if (nrow(filter(mtcars, mpg < 10) > 0)) filter(mtcars, mpg > 10) else NULL`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response; it has resolved the issue I was having.